# python - 2 math questions

Tags: python, math, geometry

Hey, I'm using pyGame and I want to:

A) make a function that returns the angle between two points. I've tried doing this with math.atan2 and I'm getting really wierd returns. I tried this with both (delta X, deltaY) and (deltaY, deltaX). Any suggestions?

B) given a length and an angle, return a point using those two from 0.
For example, LengthDir(2,45) using (length,angle) would return (2,2).

Thanks for the help. I've searched all over the internet and I couldn't find anything to help me...

Comment: Just checking: You need the angle between the lines connecting (0,0) with the two points respectively, right?

Comment: B) The length of vector `(2, 2)` isn't `2`, it's `2*sqrt(2)`.

Comment: Shouldn't `LengthDir(2, 45)` return the point `(sqrt(2), sqrt(2))`?

Comment: @KennyTM ? What you wrote equals to `2^0.5`, which is length of vector `(1, 1)`. No?

Comment: @Nikita: Sorry, you are right.

Comment: Unfortunately, searching the Internet won't help you if you don't know what you're looking for.  All the libraries in the world and all the programming you can do won't make up for a lack of knowledge of the mathematics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`math.atan2`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.atan2) returns [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian). If you need degree, multiply the result by 180/π.

```
def A(dx, dy):
  return math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / math.pi
```

Similarly, all trigonometric functions in `math` operate in radians. If you input a degree, you need to multiply by π/180 first.

```
def LengthDir(length, angle):
  radian_angle = angle * math.pi / 180
  return (length * math.cos(radian_angle), length * math.sin(radian_angle))
```

Python provides the convenient functions [`math.degrees`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.degrees) and [`math.radians`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.radians) so you don't need to memorize the constant 180/π.

```
def A(dx, dy):
  return math.degrees( math.atan2(dy, dx) )

def LengthDir(length, angle):
  radian_angle = math.radians(angle)
  return (length * math.cos(radian_angle), length * math.sin(radian_angle))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm coming from Game Maker, which had these functions built in.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the functions in [`cmath`](http://docs.python.org/library/cmath.html) to convert between rectangular and polar coordinates. For example:

```
import math, cmath

def LengthDir(r, phi):
   c = cmath.rect(r, math.radians(phi))
   return (c.real, c.imag)

def AngleBetween((x1, y1), (x2, y2)):
   phi = cmath.phase(x2 + y2*j) - cmath.phase(x1 + y1*j)
   return math.degrees(phi) % 360
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

def dist(dx,dy):
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

def ang(dx, dy):
    return math.degrees(math.atan2(dy, dx))

def offs(dist, ang):
    ang = math.radians(ang)
    dx = dist * math.cos(ang)
    dy = dist * math.sin(ang)
    return dx,dy
```

.

```
dist(2,2) -> 2.8284
ang(2,2) -> 45.0
offs(2, 45) -> (1.414, 1.414)
```