# Python: Does a module exist which already find an angle and the distance between two points?

Tags: python, math, geometry, trigonometry

First of all, I apologize to post this easy question. Probably there is a module to compute angle and distance between two points.

- A = (560023.44957588764,6362057.3904932579)
- B = (560036.44957588764,6362071.8904932579)

Comment: What do you mean by the angle between two points? You need two lines to form an angle.

Comment: I suppose they're two position vectors, and he's trying to calculate the angle between them...

Comment: Angle with respect to the origin?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909016/python-2-math-questions.

Comment: @phant0m, respect the x axis.

Comment: @Gianni Which of the infinite number of points on the X axis?

Comment: @delnan I think he does mean the origin, but good point (pun intended) :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given

[image]

you could compute the angle, `theta`, and the distance between A and B with:

```
import math
def angle_wrt_x(A,B):
    """Return the angle between B-A and the positive x-axis.
    Values go from 0 to pi in the upper half-plane, and from 
    0 to -pi in the lower half-plane.
    """
    ax, ay = A
    bx, by = B
    return math.atan2(by-ay, bx-ax)

def dist(A,B):
    ax, ay = A
    bx, by = B
    return math.hypot(bx-ax, by-ay)

A = (560023.44957588764, 6362057.3904932579)
B = (560036.44957588764, 6362071.8904932579)
theta = angle_wrt_x(A, B)
d = dist(A, B)
print(theta)
print(d)
```

which yields

```
0.839889619638  # radians
19.4743420942
```

(Edit: Since you are dealing with points in a plane, its easier to use `atan2` than the dot-product formula).

Comment: is it the angle respect the x axis? as in this example http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/how-to-find-the-minimum-area-rectangle-for-given-points

Comment: No, it is the interior angle `AOB`, where `O` is the origin.

Comment: If you want the angle between `AO` and the x-axis, then compute `angle(A, (1,0))`.

Comment: OK. I need to built a minimum-area-rectangle for given points following the example, because i didn't find this algorithm implemented in python. The first step is calculate the theta angle respect the X axis.
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/how-to-find-the-minimum-area-rectangle-for-given-points

Comment: This is my previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542855/python-help-to-implement-an-algorithm-to-find-the-minimum-area-rectangle-for-gi

Comment: Are you referring to the theta given in the picture?

Comment: yes they are part of the point of the example of the my previous post

Comment: Then to compute `theta`, use `angle(B-A, (1,0))`.

Comment: great job. You are always really great. Know I am writing a def to calculate the distance

Comment: @zch has the right answer: to compute the distance, `math.hypot(x,y)` equals `sqrt(x**2+y**2)`.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, `math` module has `atan2`. `math.atan2(y, x)` is an angle `(0, 0)` to `(x, y)`.

Also `math.hypot(x, y)` is distance form `(0, 0)` to `(x, y)`.